# How to abort old request processing when new request arrives on ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form with hundreds of check boxes and dropdown menus (Which value of many of them are coupled together). In the action there is updating mechanism to update an object in Session. This object does all validation and coupling of values, for example if user types %50 in one input filed, we might add 3 new SelectListItem to a dropdown.

Everything works fine, but if use starts to clicking on check boxes very quick (which is the normal case in our scenario), controller get multiple posts while it is processing previous ones. Fortunately we are only interested in the last POST, so we need a way to abort\cancel on going requests when newer request from same form comes.

What I tried:
1- blocking client side to make multiple posts when server still working on previous one. It is not desirable because it makes noticeable pauses on browser side.

2- There are several solutions for blocking multiple post backs by using HASH codes or AntiForgeryToken. But they don't what I need, I need to abort on-going thread in favor of new request, not blocking incoming request.

3- I tried to extend pipeline by adding two message handlers (one before action and another after executing action) to keep a hash code (or AntiForgeryToken) but problem is still there, even I can detect there is on-going thread working on same request, I have no way to abort that thread or set older request to Complete.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should look to implement a client side solution to eliminate the constant need to post back to the controller. Your SPA can then post back the entire object state when the user saves or other trigger.

Comment: It is not possible to move more than 2400 lines of code from C# to Javascript. We have all the logic including validation and data coupling in C#. 
Also our solution is not SPA, even it looks like SPA behavior in this case.

Comment: I nice Approach is build a bounce system, imagine you have a array of commands so every time a checkbox is changed you store this operation on then and you have a timeout function running every second, this function will look for the array take the last element, perform the request and clear it. This way you will have just one request per minute with the last operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help @xavier-j.
After playing around this, I wrote this. Hope it be useful for someone who needs same thing:

First you need add this ActionFilter

```
public class KeepLastRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string HashCode { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource> clt;
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Application["CancellationTokensDictionary"] != null)
        {
            clt = (Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>)filterContext.HttpContext.Application["CancellationTokensDictionary"];
        }
        else
        {
            clt = new Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>();
        }
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["__RequestVerificationToken"] != null)
        {
            HashCode = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["__RequestVerificationToken"];
        }

        CancellationTokenSource oldCt = null;
        clt.TryGetValue(HashCode, out oldCt);
        CancellationTokenSource ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
        if (oldCt != null)
        {
            oldCt.Cancel();
            clt[HashCode] = ct;
        }
        else
        {
            clt.Add(HashCode, ct);
        }

        filterContext.HttpContext.Application["CancellationTokensDictionary"] = clt;
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.CancellationToken = ct;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ThreadHasBeenCanceld == null && filterContext.HttpContext.Application["CancellationTokensDictionary"] != null) {
            lock (filterContext.HttpContext.Application["CancellationTokensDictionary"])
            {
                Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>  clt = (Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>)filterContext.HttpContext.Application["CancellationTokensDictionary"];
                clt.Remove(HashCode);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Application["CancellationTokensDictionary"] = clt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using AntiForgeryToken here as key token, you can add your own custom hash code to have more control.

In the controller you will have something like this

```
        [HttpPost]
    [KeepLastRequest]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DoSlowJob(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource ctv = ViewBag.CancellationToken;
        CancellationTokenSource nct = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct, ctv.Token, Response.ClientDisconnectedToken);

        var mt = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            SlowJob(nct.Token);
        }, nct.Token);
        await mt;

        return null;
    }

    private void SlowJob(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                this.ViewBag.ThreadHasBeenCanceld = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("cancelled!!!");
                break;
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("doing job " + (i + 1));
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("job done");

        return;
    }
```

And finally in your JavaScript you need to abort ongoing requests, otherwise browser blocks new requests.

```
        var onSomethingChanged = function () {

        if (currentRequest != null) {
            currentRequest.abort();
        }

        var fullData = $('#my-heavy-form :input').serializeArray();

        currentRequest = $.post('/MyController/DoSlowJob', fullData).done(function (data) {
            // Do whatever you want with returned data
        }).fail(function (f) {
            console.log(f);
        });
        currentRequest.always(function () {
            currentRequest = null;
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you *can* do is throttle the requests client-side. Basically, you need to set a timeout when a checkbox is clicked. You can let that initial request go through, but then any further requests are queued (or actually dropped after the first queued request in your scenario) and don't run that until the timeout clears.

There's no way to abort a request server-side. Each request is idempotent. There is no inherent knowledge of anything that's happened before or since. The server has multiple threads fielding requests and will simply process those as fast as it can. There's no order to how the requests are processed or how responses are sent out. The first request could be the third one that receives a response, simply due to how the processing of each request goes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement transactional functionality (i.e. counting only the last request) over an asynchronous technology.  This is a design flaw.

Since you refuse to block on the client side, you have no method by which to control which requests process first, OR to correctly process the outcome again on the client-side.

You might actually run into this scenario:

1. Client sends Request A
2. Server starts processing Request B
3. Client sends Request B
4. Server starts processing Request B
5. Server returns results of Request B, and client changes accordingly
6. Server returns results of Request A, and client changes accordingly (and undoes prior changes resulting from Request B)

Blocking is the only way you can ensure the correct order.